# Empty a NodeList

Tags: javascript, removechild, splice, nodelist

I have this code in javascript

```js
var variables = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
var array = [];
while(variables.length > 0){
  array.push(variables[0].innerHTML);
  //Variables 0th index must remove here
}
```

I want to remove 0th index of node list `variables`.
Similar to `splice` method in arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Use [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and be sure to convert the nodeList to an array

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
var variables = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);//convert to array

var array = [];
while(variables.lenght > 0){
  array.push(variables[0].innerHTML);
  variables.shift();
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cjdb0vv8/4/)

Comment: But shift method is for arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular old `for` loop:

```
var variables = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
var array = [];
while (var i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
  array.push(variables[i].innerHTML);
}
```

In modern JS, one might use `map` instead:

```
function getInnerHtml(elt) { return elt.innerHTML; }

Array.prototype.map.call(variables, getInnerHtml);
```